# How to Check Mobile/Web in HTML Meteor?

Tags: meteor

How to check **Mobile/Web** in HTML Meteor for loading UI? .

```
if mobile //here how to check if it is mobile or web
{
   {{>template}}// mobile body
}
else
{
  {{>template}}//web body
}
```

I am new to Meteor. So please suggest me what to do?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-handheld-device-in-jquery

Comment: if you want to do this on the client then there is nothing special about meteor here. Please just look for answers for html/javascript. You could also just use one of many responsive design frameworks (e.g., bootstrap, or foundation). On the server this would be a lot harder.

Comment: Actually, while you can do this in typical JS / JQuery way, Meteor makes it easier. The question is legit.

Comment: There is a [good discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/ku7kvNJp8ek) over at the meteor-talk google group regarding this very subject.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do that easily with [device-detection](https://atmospherejs.com/mystor/device-detection) package.

First, install it via:

```
meteor add mystor:device-detection
```

Then you can use the provided helper methods like `Meteor.Device.isPhone()`, or directly from Spacebars: `{{#if isPhone}}Phone{{/if}}`. See [the readme on Github](https://github.com/mystor/meteor-device-detection) for details.

Comment: that package is no longer supported. Is there a new preferred method?

Comment: Ever find an answer for this?

Answer (score 5):

If you simply want to check whether the app is running on a mobile environment you can use:

```
if(Meteor.isCordova)
```

Check out the [other functions](https://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-isCordova) as well

Answer (score 1):

If someone is still looking for this, he can try this JS test:

```
if (/Mobi/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    //on Mobile
}else{
    //not on mobile
}
```