# Blaze global helpers are not working with MeteorJS Mobile

Tags: javascript, meteor, mobile, meteor-blaze

I have two templates. The first is browser based called "home" and the second is mobile (iOS and Android) called "mobileHome".

I have tried every known version of registering a global helper possible and while they appear on the browser template they do not appear on the mobile version.

main.js

```
Template.registerHelper('groupId', function () {    
  return 'hi, madeup group id here';
});    

Handlebars.registerHelper('isMainApp', function () {
  console.log('hello')
  return 'hello this is mobileMainApp';
});

UI.registerHelper('what', function () {
  return 'what ui call';
});

UI.body.helpers({
  fund: function(){
    return 'hey template .body';
  }
})
```

Any suggestions to make the above appear in mobile environments?

Comment: You can try the answers suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21745538/how-to-check-mobile-web-in-html-meteor) to find about the environment.

Comment: @SudheerJami Thanks for that but I already know how to determine if it's a mobile or web. 

My issue is related to global helpers not being registered in mobile environments.